# Using a pointer on a class method : Expression must have type bool error

Tags: c++, string, pointers

So, I have a string* which I used for a dynamic array. But when I try to use a string method on it, I get the error Expression must have type bool.

For Instance, I get the error when I try to do it on this piece of code

```
while((!board[i].clear())
{

}
```

Comment: Parens aren't matched, but that probably isn't the real issue.

Comment: It does return anything it gives an error. It should return true if the string is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using the `std:string` class, it's `clear()` method has a `void` return type. You cannot use it in a boolean expression like you are attempting to.

**EDIT**

Link for you [string clear method](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/clear/)

Comment: Oh now I get I it, I need to use the empty method, but I got it confused with clear.